# sony-camera-api - CameraRemoteAPIbeta - deleteContent/actFormatStorage

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

In the reference guide of the Sony Camera Remote API SDK (Sony_CameraRemoteAPIbeta_API-Reference_v2.10.pdf) the methods `deleteContent` and `getContentList` are documented.

But using the Sony Camera Remote API SDK with a Sony QX1 the methods `deleteContent` and `getContentList` are not listed in the results of `getAvailableApiList` (neither in "Remote Shooting" nor "Contents Transfer" mode).

I assume that they are therefore not available?

How can the photos on the SD card be deleted or formatted?

Running `getAvailableApiList` does list `actFormatStorage` in "Remote Shooting" Mode. How can this be applied?

Comment: Is this question referencing a question/answer on StackOverflow?  If so edit your question and add a link to it.  Otherwise please add more details to your question and give  examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: there's no link to add. I just edited my questions and added more details. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to delete files from the camera using the following sequence of calls:

- setCameraFunction to "Contents Transfer"
- getSourceList to get storage location
- getContentCount to get count of files
- getContentList to get list of files on camera
- parse content list to get file URI's
- deleteContent to delete each file

I am also trying to figure out how to use the actFormatStorage, but no luck so far

Comment: thank you for your feedback! I just skip getContentCount

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you have the latest firmware installed on your camera.  The "deleteContent" API is only available in API version 1.1 and "getContentList" in API version 1.3.

Also, after re-reading your question the "getAvailableApiList" only returns methods that are part of the "camera" service.  "deleteContent" and "getContentList" are part of the "avContent" service and they won't be listed when you call "getAvailableApiList".

Instead you should call "getMethodTypes" to list the methods of the "avContent" service.  See the section on page 10 of the API reference called "Supported APIs and availalble APIs" for more details.

Comment: Hi Marlin. "getVersions" does give the following result in "Remote Shooting" and "Contents Transfer" Mode --> {"result":[["1.0","1.1","1.2"]],"id":1}

Comment: It looks like my QX1 doesn't support API version 1.3. How can the firmware be updated? How can "actFormatStorage" be applied?

Comment: "deleteContent" and "getContentList" are not listed also when I switch to "Contents Transfer" (using ("method", method: "setCameraFunction"), params: "Contents Transfer") and call "getMethodTypes". 

Can you give any information about the usage of "actFormatStorage"

Comment: "deleteContent" should be listed.  What does your request look like when you call "getMethodTypes"?  Are you ensuring you are passing the version as 1.1 to the request?  "getContentList" won't be listed since your camera does not support API version 1.3.  Unfortunately actFormatStorage is not a supported API even thought it is listed.

Comment: I'm using json in a python script. ("method", "getMethodTypes"),("params", []),("id", 1),("version", "1.0")]). Changing to ("version","1.1") does return {"id":1,"error":[3,"Illegal Argument"]} in  "Remote Shooting" and "Contents Transfer"

Comment: Your request looks ok to me.  Did you ensure you are using the /avContent endpoint?

Comment: Hi Marlin! Thank you for all your efforts. combining all infos allows me to delete file by file...