# Capture still image from sony camera in c#

Tags: sony-camera-api

I'm developing a WPF c# apllication that is processing images on a .NET  Framework enviroment for destop pcs

Q1: Is it possible to capture still images from a Sony camera using the Remote api sdk (i see examples only for ios and android). was wondering because it uses http and json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use the Camera Remote API from a desktop PC because as you noted it is a REST based API.  There is currently no sample code available in the SDK for this however.  But there are some open source projects that have been done by independent developers that may be a good starting point.

Comment: Any plans to add 'delete contents' support to all the cameras? This is such a basic feature and missing for years now, it is a shame as we can't really take this API seriously.

Another issue is, do the ActionCams support an 'always on' mode yet? That is as soon as power is restored they come back online and connect to wifi? Without this, as you can imagine the APIs use is very limited as you always need to be with the camera to turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

This link has an outline of commands to use the deleteContent command.

[sony-camera-api - CameraRemoteAPIbeta - deleteContent/actFormatStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852936/sony-camera-api-cameraremoteapibeta-deletecontent-actformatstorage/33355396#33355396)

1. setCameraFunction to "Contents Transfer"
2. getSourceList to get storage location
3. getContentCount to get count of files
4. getContentList to get list of files on camera
5. parse content list to get file URI's
6. deleteContent to delete each file

The API Docs show which cameras support this command. I am using it with the ILCE-QX1.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/device-support/

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/get-started/