# Sony QX1 deleteContent API

Tags: api, sony, sony-camera-api

I have a Sony QX1 camera and I want to delete the contents of the SD Card using the Sony Camera Remote API. The available API versions on the camera are 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

According to the documentation, the "deleteContent" API is available in API version 1.1. The problem is that I need to provide the URI of an image in the deleteContent request. The documentation refers to "getContentList" to get these URI's, but this API is only available in version 1.3.

How can I use the deleteContent API then? Is there any other way to format the SD card/remove all content with an API < 1.2 ? Or is there a way to update the QX1 camera to a newer firmware which has API 1.3?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The post below has information on this.

[sony-camera-api - CameraRemoteAPIbeta - deleteContent/actFormatStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852936/sony-camera-api-cameraremoteapibeta-deletecontent-actformatstorage/33355396#33355396)

I have been able to delete files from the camera using the following sequence of calls:

• setCameraFunction to "Contents Transfer"

• getSourceList to get storage location

• getContentCount to get count    of files

• getContentList to get list of files on camera

• parse content list to get file URI's

• deleteContent to delete each file

you need to call the API with the right version for each call and be in the right mode for that call.  You need to switch to "Contents Transfer" mode to copy and delete files.

Comment: `The documentation refers to "getContentList" to get these URI's, but this API is only available in version 1.3.`

Comment: Each command you send has a version field and you put the right version in each command so the 'getContentList' would have version '1.3'.  But the 'deleteContent' would need version '1.1'.  I have used this with the QX1 camera successfully.

Comment: But when I check which API versions my QX1 supports (using getVersions), 1.3 is not in the list ? I will try to use the API by adding the version header with 1.3 in it.

Comment: There are different getVersions results for each camera url.  The avContent url should respond with all the versions the API supports