# Deleting content from Sony a6300 camera

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am developing a python remote control application using the open source pysony library. The program should be able to shoot images in a loop, download them and then delete the artifacts on the camera (We can't manually format the sd card, since the idea is that, of a remote control application).

I'd like to point out, that I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852936/sony-camera-api-cameraremoteapibeta-deletecontent-actformatstorage) post about the correct way of remotely deleting files. I have read the Sony API documentation and have successfully managed to control everything I need to, but the deletion of images. The camera in question is a Sony a6300, updated to the latest firmware as is its API.

The problem in question is the fact that the camera returns a success response ({'result': [], 'id': 1}) after trying to delete a set of image URIs, but the images still remain on the camera. I am using the remote control app and am connected directly to the camera wifi (making this the standard 1:1 connection). When I issue the delete command, the screen of the camera shortly displays a "controlling with smartphone... you cannot directly operate this device" message.

I have searched all around the www an can't seem to find and aswer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before running the delete commands did you switch the camera into Contents Transfer mode? You can do this using the "setCameraFunction" method and specifying the parameter as "Contents Transfer". You can read more on page 190 and 265 of the documentation. Actually here is a great post walking through some of the steps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852936/sony-camera-api-cameraremoteapibeta-deletecontent-actformatstorage

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to mention the camera is indeed in Contents Transfer mode, I doubled checked with the call of the appropriate get function to make sure after setting it.

Comment: I have had another user have success by simply updating the playmemories app on your android device. This honestly should not make a different, but can you try updating your app to see if anything changes? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.playmemories.mobile

Comment: We are developing a custom application, which does not use a mobile device. We double checked that the camera firmware and the playmemories application on the camera is updated.

Comment: ok I see. Can you post the exact command you are calling to delete the contents? Maybe that can give me a better idea of what the issue is.

Comment: Posted directly to Pastebin (not sure this is the correct way?). https://pastebin.com/iHCPA8Z7. Note that __get_camera_function and __set_camera_function do exactly what they say (I double checked that part).

Comment: Thanks for the pastebin post! Sorry for not clarifying, but what I was really hoping for was the json body you send to the camera and the JSON that it replies with. Are you able to post that information?